# Changing entry point of a java file

Tags: java

I have a decompiled Jar file and it's overriding the regular main method entry point. Is there any way to convert it to such?

I have tried an open source and successfully decompiled it. However, when I tried to run it, it says the codes don't have the main method to even execute.

Here's what i'm working on: http://www.zenlunatics.com/quizcards/

It has an executable jar version and a version with the directory and java files in it.

Please help.

Thanks!

Comment: Is it an executable JAR file?

Answer (score 1):

The main method class should be mentioned in manifest file like `Main-Class: MyPackage.MyClass`. The main class should have `public static void main(String a[])`

Ref: [Setting an Application's Entry Point](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html)

Answer (score 0):

For Extracting the source  you should use the command prompt like **jar vcf file address** and many other required option **jar **  command

Comment: i'm using JD Gui for it.